# Assert.notThrown with possibility to specify a message if exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, assert, assertions

I use Spring Asserts in my project and want to use them (or perhaps some other Asserts) to check if exception is thrown in some situations, for instance I have the following code:

```
//throws PatternSyntaxException in case if pattern is invalid

Pattern.compile(freeUsersRegex);
Pattern.compile(deletedUsersRegex);
Pattern.compile(movedUsersReges);
...
```

I want to specify a message in case if regex is invalid (every time different) to show user which one regular expression is invalid, something like that:

```
    try {
        Pattern.compile(freeUsersRegex);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException e ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specify valid regular expression for Free users group");
    }

    try {
        Pattern.compile(deletedUsersRegex);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException e ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specify valid regular expression for Deleted users group");
    }
    ...
```

But writing try/catch for every string is not very convenient, it would be cool to replace the code above with something like that:

```
Assert.isNotThrown(Pattern.compile(freeUsersRegex), PatternSyntaxException.class, "Specify valid regular expression for Free users group");

Assert.isNotThrown(Pattern.compile(deletedUsersRegex), PatternSyntaxException.class, "Specify valid regular expression for Deleted users group");
```

I looked for such Assert in Spring and was unable to find it. Perhaps there is something like that in other libraries?

Thanks,

Andrey

Comment: you want to use assertions to validate your pattern or for a unit test?

Comment: Not for unit test, to validate patterns before my Service class starts and to indicate that pattern is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply reusing a utility method of type:

```
public static Pattern createPattern(String regex, String type){
    try {
        return Pattern.compile(regex);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException e ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            String.format("Specify valid regular expression for %s", type)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a possibility for sure, but I want to reuse some existing sollution as I need to catch not only PatternSyntaxException but a dozen of

Comment: there is no magic the exceptions must be caught and managed somewhere

Comment: Yeah, I understand that but it might be that this functionality (like yours but generic like) is implemented somewhere via reflection; So just not to reinvent the bicycle I'm looking for something which is already implemented as I have many situations like in the initial post in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to [Javaslang](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/wiki/Try-examples) and [Cyclop](http://www.javaslang.io/javaslang-docs/#_try) which both have Try implementations.

Cyclops Try only captures Exceptions during specific 'withCatch' phases - which correspond to the initialisation and main execution phases

Following is an example of Cyclop's Try:

```
Try.withCatch(()-> Pattern.compile(freeUsersRegex))
   .onFail(PatternSyntaxException.class, 
              e -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specify valid regular expression for Free users group"));
```

Javaslang Try is very similar to the Scala Try and will capture all Exceptions thrown at any stage during composition.

Following is an example of Javaslang's Try:

```
Try.of(()-> Pattern.compile(freeUsersRegex))
    .recover(e -> Match(e).of(
        Case(instanceOf(PatternSyntaxException.class), throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specify valid regular expression for Free users group")),
    ));
```